# VueJS and SVG - Nested iterations over array and conditional rendering based on element type

Tags: svg, vue.js

I have an array of objects that gets passed to my SVG component as props. That array is filled with different shapes (in example circle and rect.) I would like to render all the elements in my svg but i cant figure out how to construct the outer loop. (my assumption here is that it is only possible with nested loop)

```
elements:[
  {
    type:"circle",
    items:[
        {
          x:12,
          y:13
        },
        {
          x:30,
          y:40
        }
      ]
    },

  {
    type:"rectangles",
    items:[
        {
          x:22,
          y:33
        },
        {
          x:40,
          y:50
        }
      ]
    }

  ]
```

SVG : in the object comment I would like to have outer loop that i would iterate over and based on the "type" key value I could then conditionally render whatever i need based on whether it is circle or rect. etc..

```
    <!-- <object v-for="item in elements> -->

  <circle v-if="item.type='circles'" v-for="item in elements[0].items"
    :cx="item.x"
    :cy="item.y"
    :r="5"/>

<!-- </object> -->
```

I cant figure out how to make the outer loop that will iterate through the array

Sandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/oqqnwm8vpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need nested loops as you have an array of elements, in each element has an array of items. So your template should look something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <svg id="svg1" style="background: #808080">

      <template v-for="elem in elements">

        <template v-if="elem.type == 'circle'">
          <circle v-for="item in elem.items" :cx="item.x" :cy="item.y" r="5" />
        </template>

        <template v-if="elem.type == 'rectangles'">
          <rect
            v-for="item in elem.items"
            :x="item.x - 5"
            :y="item.y - 5"
            width="10"
            height="10"
          />
        </template>

      </template>

    </svg>
  </div>
</template>
```

So the outer loop is:

```
<template v-for="elem in elements">
```

Then there's a check for the type of elements:

```
<template v-if="elem.type == 'circle'">
```

And finally the innermost tag is again a loop for all items:

```
<circle v-for="item in elem.items" :cx="item.x" :cy="item.y" r="5" />
```

Note that I'm using the `template` tag in order to avoid that the outer loop and the *if* conditions generate tags of their own. That way we get no additional nesting within the `svg` element:

```
<svg data-v-763db97b="" id="svg1" style="background: rgb(128, 128, 128);">
    <circle data-v-763db97b="" cx="12" cy="13" r="5"></circle>
    <circle data-v-763db97b="" cx="30" cy="40" r="5"></circle>
    <rect data-v-763db97b="" x="17" y="28" width="10" height="10"></rect>
    <rect data-v-763db97b="" x="35" y="45" width="10" height="10"></rect>
</svg>
```

**Update**

BTW: Your code contains two hidden bugs in `v-if="item.type='circles'`. Instead of comparing with "circles", you assign the value "circles". And you should be comparing to "circle" (and not "circles").

Comment: Thank you. Was never aware of <template> tag and its usefulness in these situations.If I need to iterate I usually use <div> tha cant be used in this case. Cheers!